# Td with "undefined" values

Tags: html, angular, html-table, undefined

I want to replace my "undefined" values in my table with " ", to get only empty cells.

This is what i tried:

```
    <tr *ngFor="let name of data">
            <td>
                {{name !== undefined ? name : ''}}
            </td>
```

Nothing changed, how can i manage the undefined values?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

If name contains any real value it will be used, otherwise empty string

```
 {{name || ''}}
```

If name contains "undefined" world as string, rule above will print that string

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
{{ name ? name : ''}}
```

so whenever name is falsy, and `undefined` is falsy, it will return an empty string, when it's truthy it will return `name`.